# How can i write a code for the below scenario in webdriver

Tags: webdriver

How can i write a code for the below scenario in webdriver

In a page there are two text boxes.

what ever the integers given in the text box should be added.for example give 23.this should get added as 2+3.

The added value should be entered in the second text box.

Can any one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

public static void main (String args[]){

```
int sum = 0;
System.out.println("Enter multi digit number:");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = input.nextInt();
int t = n;
while (n > 0) {
        int p = n % 10;
        sum = sum + p;
        n = n / 10;
}

System.out.println("sum of the digits in " + t + " is " + sum);
```

}